# I am getting an error every time I load any unity project and cannot find a fix

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

Whenever I load any unity project I get this warning: Win32Exception:

> ApplicationName='C:\Program
> Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.10f1\Editor\Data\Tools\RoslynScripts\unity_csc.bat',
> CommandLine='/noconfig
> @Temp/UnityTempFile-5f84a32cf955fcc4bb66b280c644997c',
> CurrentDirectory='', Native error= The system cannot find the file
> specified.
>
> System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess
> (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) (at
> :0) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
> () (at :0) (wrapper
> remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
> UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start (System.EventHandler exitCallback) (at
> :0) UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start
> () (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.MicrosoftCSharpCompiler.BeginCompiling
> () (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTask.QueuePendingAssemblies
> () (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTask.Poll () (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileScriptAssemblies
> (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssembly[]
> scriptAssemblies,
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssemblySettings
> scriptAssemblySettings, System.String tempBuildDirectory,
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTaskOptions
> compilationTaskOptions,
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation+CompileScriptAssembliesOptions
> compileScriptAssembliesOptions) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileScriptsWithSettings
> (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssemblySettings
> scriptAssemblySettings, System.String tempBuildDirectory,
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.TargetAssembly[]&
> notCompiledTargetAssemblies, System.String[]& notCompiledScripts,
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTaskOptions
> compilationTaskOptions) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileScripts
> (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorScriptCompilationOptions
> editorScriptCompilationOptions, UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup
> platformGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget platform, System.String[]
> extraScriptingDefines,
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTaskOptions
> compilationTaskOptions) (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface+<>c__DisplayClass40_0.b__0
> () (at :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface.EmitExceptionAsError[T]
> (System.Func`1[TResult] func, T returnValue) (at
> :0)
> UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface:CompileScriptsNoStop(EditorScriptCompilationOptions,
> BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget, String[])

I am running windows 10, unity 2020.3.10f1, and have created an empty
3d project. This error pops up immediately after starting a new
project. I also get an error when I try and add a pre-existing c#
script to an object:

> The script don't inherit a native class that can
> manage a script

When I add a c# script as a component to an object
(Cube (1)) directly I get the errors "The referenced script
(PlayerMovement) on this Behaviour is missing!" and "The referenced
script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Cube (1)') is missing!"

I have tried:

Running `unity_csc.bat` manually (through file explorer and cmd) to make sure that it's running as intended (which I believe it is, although I could be wrong).

Making sure that the c# class has the same name as the file.

Starting a new project.

Redownloading unity 2020.3.10f1

So far nothing has worked and I am very new to unity so I am unsure of what else to try, I think it could be something wrong with my system files in which case I may have to reinstall windows but I would rather not have to do that. I also am fairly inexperienced with StackOverflow so please tell me if I am missing necessary information. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Please copy error messages & warnings directly into your question as text.  There are many reasons that is preferable to a screenshot or summary; one of those reasons is that the error messages usually are conveying more information than you realize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the things suggested to me here I fixed the issue by downloading the unity editor from [here](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) instead of from the unity hub. I am unsure of why this worked but it did so I'm not complaining. If you are having the same issue as me then click the link and click the version of unity you want, then click the drop-down for either mac or windows depending on what you're using and click unity editor.

(also at some point between me asking my original question and me fixing it unity stopped allowing me to get further than the unity hub but I am pretty sure that this will fix it for you even if this isn't happening.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you OS has some problem with cmd. This issue has happened for more people, and the culprit is cmd not being able to run. You should look into that, not the file system.

Comment: What do you mean cmd might not be able to run? I can run cmd manually, might there be an issue with the system running cmd itself?

Answer (score -1):

This must be the Warning, not error.